# Efficient way to implement newsfeed

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a simple social network.

Say I have two models: `Status` and my custom `UserProfile` model to implement followers/followings feature:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Status(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='statuses')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    status = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Status"
        verbose_name_plural = "Statuses"
        ordering = ('-created',)
        get_latest_by = 'created'


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    followings = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self', related_name='followers', symmetrical=False, blank=True)
```

What is the most efficient way to access newsfeed i.e. recent `statuses` of all of my(`User`) `followings`?

I am new to Django. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply filter `Status` queryset by users that you are following. Query above will show all statuses for all users followed by `user`.

```
Status.objects.filter(user__followers=user)
```

Comment: Thanks! But your answer is not 100% correct.  `Status.objects.filter(user__profile__followers=user.profile)` does the job. Is this the most efficient way?

Comment: You can also create queryset like this: `Status.objects.filter(user__in=User.objects.filter(profile__followers=user.profile))`. But which one is better will depend on amount of data in each table and database engine used.